# How can I easily distinguish between eukaryotic and prokaryotic cells using flow cytometry?

Tags: yeast, eukaryotic-cells, staining, flow-cytometry, prokaryotic-cells

I am trying to count populations of cells in a co-culture. One organism is *Pichia pastoris* and the other organism is a gram-negative bacterium. Pichia stains gram-positive using crystal violet and the bacterium is negative. These two populations are reasonably distinct in front and side scatter but not so much that I can gate the entire population. I can pick a region in FSC-SCC for each organism that I know will only include that organism, which is 'good enough' for my purposes, but I'd love to know if there is a quick, easy, cheap way to distinguish these two populations more decisively. To clarify my requirements:

- Cheap: Ideally something widely available in the price range of <$1/sample e.g. Hoechst/Van-Bodipy/WGA-647
- No processing steps: I just want to add the dye/stain to my sample automatically using the flow cytometer before running the samples

Things I have considered but have ruled out:

- Antibodies: They are too expensive for my case. I would need a custom conjugated antibody or to add processing steps between primary and secondary antibody that is too complicated.
- Tracker/tracer dyes (add to one cell population before mixing the co-culture together): Also expensive, and I will probably want to track my population over more generations than most of these dyes work for.
- Intracellular markers that require permeabilisation: I don't want to do any processing

Things I'm considering and would welcome input on:

- Conjugated lectins, specific to glycoproteins on *Pichia pastoris*
- DNA dyes, using the fact that *Pichia* genome is approx 2x larger than the bacterial genome
- Differing autofluorescence: There's nothing obviously different here from my data so far, but I will go back and tweak the voltages etc. if this is a very promising avenue
- Any combination of stains/techniques that are not specific alone, but then the populations can be separated using e.g. PCA

Is there anything out there that will work for me? It seems to me that the cell types are so different there must be an easier solution here than expensive antibodies etc. An answer of "No" would be just as valid as yes! I can continue just using front and side scatter if the only solutions are going to be too complicated.

Comment: Acridine orange might work for nucleic acid content. You might want to check out the Molecular Probes Handbook for some options Ch8 and 15.

Comment: Ok to kill the cells you are counting?

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler Sure, but only if it's not too complicated/doesn't involve too much waiting

Comment: What about using cell size? The prokaryotes should be much smaller.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I do see a difference in forward scatter on the flow cytometer, which correlates with cell size, and it's 'good enough' when combined with a difference in side scatter. I'm wondering if there's a third dimension that I can separate them on that will make it totally unambiguous.

Comment: If you kill one population, the dead cells will be easily permeable to various dyes.